# What are the risks of setting VirtualBox CPU count up to the *logical* CPU count?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, performance, virtualization

The GUI and the [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor) of VirtualBox warn about setting virtual CPU count higher than the *physical* CPU count:

> You should not, however, configure virtual machines to use more CPU cores than you have available physically (real cores, no hyperthreads).

However, no more details are provided. I tried to find additional information on this topic and found contradictory recommendations:

1. > You should *never* assign all your cores as vCPUs in a  virtual machine.
   >
   > https://superuser.com/a/273544/84807

   But the comments claim it to be outdated.
2. There is another similar question with contradictory answers: [Quad Core host with hyper-threading, how many processors to configure in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/668245/quad-core-host-with-hyper-threading-how-many-processors-to-configure-in-virtual)
   [The accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1179451/84807) warns of errors and even BSOD, most other answers and comments don’t see any problems. Especially interesting is the link to http://envobi.com/post/virtualbox-hyper-threading-benchmark-surprise/.
3. The benchmarks presented at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325932/virtualbox-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-assign-more-virtual-cpu-cores-than-number-of-phy show that a multi-threaded application running in a VM can profit from the additional CPUs. It looks promising for me but I still have the following questions.

**What are the risks of setting CPU count in VirtualBox up to the *logical* CPU count of the machine? Why does VirtualBox discourage it?**

I basically aim at running a multi-threaded, CPU-limited<sup>*)</sup> application in the VM at the best possible performance while the host is idle. My computer has an [Intel® Core™ i7-4770 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/75122/Intel-Core-i7-4770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz).

*) I mean it can utilize the performance of all CPUs I offer to it and is not primarily limited by RAM or I/O.

Comment: I once did exactly this and it crashed my computer to the point where I had to reinstall the whole thing. Not sure if this is the exact problem that crashed it. p.s friends of mine did it too and had the same problem