# Virtual Machine client slow and crashing

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, memory, cpu, centos-7

Admittedly I am working VirtualBox quite hard with this idea. I have a 32 Intel core (64 HT core), 128 GB workstation running CentOS 7. I am looking to run Windows in virtual machines, ideally in 16 to 24 core occupation, with up to 64 GB RAM.

However on execution, the Windows boot is very slow, and slower with more cores until boot just stops all together. 64 GB memory allocation takes minutes during boot as well.

Is this level of operation just not what VirtualBox is good for? Is my host machine just not configured correctly? Is the client installation not correct? Am I missing something else fundamental?

Is VirtualBox locked to cores still, and that calling up all cores will lock up the host and the client as in [this question?](https://superuser.com/questions/21977/is-there-an-optimal-setting-for-the-number-of-cpu-cores-exposed-to-a-vm)

**Spec:**

- 2x Intel XEON E5-2698 v3 (x64)
- ASUS Z10PE D16 WS
- Host: Centos 7 (x64)
- Client: Windows 7 (x64)

Comment: What is the bitness (32,64) of the VM? What is the CPU model? Is in the BIOS both VT-d VT-x are enabled (they might have other names on different CPUs)?

Comment: I've noticed incredible slowness when using a VM created as a 64bit machine but installing or booting a 32bit OS.

Comment: Added the bittedness, everything is x64. As for the virtualisation, I'm to be fair struggling to find that in the motherboard/bios configuration.